# asp.net core OAuth access_token verification fails with "IDX10609: Decryption failed. No Keys tried: token: 'System.String'.:"

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have a single page application in Blazor WASM that connects to OAuth0 and receives JWT token when a user get authenticated via OAuth.
My OAuth application uses symmetric signing with HS256.

I am trying to authenticate the returned tokens using the "Client Secret" from my OAuth app but whereas the id_token gets verified, the access_token always fails with the error:

```
"IDX10609: Decryption failed. No Keys tried: token: 'System.String'.:"
```

To perform the verification I use the method found [here](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/manually-validating-rs256-jwt-dotnet/).

My code looks like that:

```
    var mySecret = "####";
    var mySecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mySecret));
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    try
    {
        IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager = 
            new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                $"{my_oauth_app_domain}.well-known/openid-configuration", 
                new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
        OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConfig = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        var keys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys;
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateActor = false,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ValidateTokenReplay = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = mySecurityKey,
            IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys,
        }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}: {ex.StackTrace}");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

What I find strange is that the access_token appears to be malformed. I know that it doesn't have to follow the JWT specs but puting it in jwt.io causes an error and fields like "kid" which I have seen in other tokens on the web, are missing.
Here is the token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9nYW50b25vcG91bG9zLmV1LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8ifQ..MQnqWWfe3mBCVeKQ.y8e77jf3VwJNRSoDWjB3v05WrT9IJPL_kdqhxlQFnfMOAyqQJOD1ttl1muYlCJJVwAskaAeBr4FgkcwjiL1s4eS9gcWK7yq-2PPbLkDzXtBjA4kgMGdGyMURl-F2jYBNwxbCuXyBKcxJVwzE4-aluYCAOZ8QaXzqKgmQJdpxIdBluVux7nK49uhvEJ5Pv7ueh7eGcm9AAmHm__TYKPPcpPutHNiuD6J8xoptHFLPjKakECE6ZXgD-xLNp4BHwe_DmW6UDPuZ_OD9G8D-hwayz8l--zZdICEnFywUzSWXFiVPUvn4DszDhzWbJsBNf3dnl2cnKel3EYsB.NvsUTcP9v_iicpQ5AkaC4w
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem [here](https://community.auth0.com/t/access-token-is-malformed-jwt-when-authenticating-with-google-oauth2/74218). In my request to OAuth0 I did not add the "audience" parameter. This led to an opaque token being issued.